# Refactoring methods with classes implenting IList<T>

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

We made some classes with .NET Framework 3.5, who are like the following ones:

```
public class A 
{
    public override string ID { get; set; }
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    private List<B> versionen = new List<B>();
    public List<B> Versionen
    {
        get { return versionen; }
        set { versionen = value; }
    }
}
```

used by methods in an other class like

```
private static void DoSomething(List<A> versioningObj)
{
    foreach (A concretClassAObject in versioningObj)
    {
        foreach (B concretClassAVersionObject in concretClassAObject.Versionen)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

To refactor this code and developing a common method, I try to implement the following interfaces:

```
public interface VersioningObject<T> : IIDIdentifiable where T : IIDIdentifiable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<T> Versionen { get; set; }
}

public interface IIDIdentifiable
{
    string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Class A implements 'VersioningObject' and class B implements 'IIDDIdentifiable'. The new method looks like this:

```
private static void DoSomething(List<VersioningObject<IIDIdentifiable>> versioningObj)
{
    foreach (VersioningObject<IIDIdentifiable> concretClassAObject in versioningObj)
    {
        foreach(IIDIdentifiable concretClassAVersionObject in concretClassAObject.Versionen) {
        }
    }
}
```

I try to call this method 'DoSomething' like:

```
List<A> myList = new List<A>() {new A()};
DoSomething(myList);
```

and get the following errors:

- Can not be converted "System.Collection.Generic.List" to "System.Collection.Generic.List>"

  - The best overloaded method match for DoSomeThing(System.Collections.Generic.List>) has some invalid arguments

How could I solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your question makes no sense. First what is `B`? Secondly, `DoSomething` has void return type?

Comment: Why the generic `VersioningObject<T>` if you restrict `T` to `IIDIdentifiable`? Why not let `VersioningObject` have a `List<IIDIdentifiable> Versionen`?

Comment: Btw. the title is a bit misleading. None of your classes is implementing `IList<T>`.

Comment: Sorry two incorrect items:

Comment: Class A implements 'Versioning<IIDIdentifiable>' and the call to the method has to be: DoSomething(myList); not var test = DoSomething(myList); 'B' ist simply a class implementing IIDIdentifiable

Comment: Thank you Corak for your comments! First, changing the Interface from VersionObject<T> restricted to IIDIdentifiable to 'VersioningObject<IIDIdentifiable>' makes no different. Second, the class 'A' could not have a property like 'List<IIDIdentifiable> Versionen' because this property will be filled by deserialization and this deserialization process does not know the interface typ 'IIDIdentifiable' and 'A' has more members to deserialize as the Interface defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `List` nor `VersioningObject` are covariant with respect to their generic arguments.  Because of this `VersioningObject<Child>` is not implicitly convertible to `VersioningObject<Parent>` (where `Child` extends `Parent`).  And even if it were (currently it couldn't be covariant as it accepts the generic argument as input) then a `List<VersioningObject<Child>>` still wouldn't be implicitly convertible to a `List<VersioningObject<Parent>>`.

To do all of this you'll need to make several fairly fundamental refactors.

1) `VersioningObject` will need to only expose how to read the values, not write to them, thus allowing it to become conceptually covariant:

```
public interface VersioningObject<out T> : IIDIdentifiable where T : IIDIdentifiable
{
    string Name { get; }
    List<T> Versionen { get; }
}
```

2) `DoSomething` will need to accept an `IEnumerable`, not a `List`.  `IEnumerable` is covariant, since it only ever allows the reading of data using the generic argument.  `DoSomething` only ever needs to iterate the data in what you've shown, so this should be just fine.  If you need to actually use `List` specific members then this is simply impossible.

```
private static void DoSomething(
    IEnumerable<VersioningObject<IIDIdentifiable>> versioningObj)
{
   //...
}
```

Additionally generic covariance was only added in .NET 4.0, so you'll need to be using that version of the framework for any of this to be an option.